# How can I implement Describable for Bool?

Tags: haskell

I am reading  Get Programming with Haskell by Will Kurt.

It says:

> To help solidify the idea, you’ll write a simple type class of your
> own. Because you’re learning Haskell, a great type class to have is
> Describable . Any type that’s an instance of your Describable type
> class can describe itself to you in plain English. So you require only
> one function, which is describe . For whatever type you have, if it’s
> Describable , calling describe on an instance of the type will tell
> you all about it. For example, if Bool were Describable , you’d expect
> this:
>
> ```
> GHCi> describe True
> "A member of the Bool class, True is opposite of False"
> GHCi> describe False
> "A member of the Bool class, False is the opposite of True"
> ```

The code provided is:

```
class Describable a where
    describe :: a -> String
```

i think i have to use `deriving (Describable)` on Bool type. Then have to implement the `describe` function. However, I am not sure how the code will actually look like.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use `deriving` for the classes that support auto-deriving, which won't work for this `Describable` class. You'll need to create an `instance`:

```
class Describable a where
    describe :: a -> String

instance Describable Bool where
    describe True = "..."
    describe False = "..."
```

Comment: Actually, modern GHC allows a whole bunch of additional ways for deriving instances, but none of them seem appropriate for this application.

Comment: @leftaroundabout can you please give few keywords so that we can google and learn more about it.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail `DerivingStrategies` is the most general. But since you seem to be new to classes entirely, I recommend you forget about that for now and just practice writing instances by hand instead. As I said, for your example no deriving would help anyway.